# Word Office 2013 index

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

I created an index using word office 2013 using 3 columns; the problem is that the writing is always from the right to left no matter what i do.

i need to have the columns form the left to the right; please help me

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the columns are typed into on the right side of the page first or the text types from the right side to the left or both.
This link show and explains right to left text, tables, etc. It is the reverse to return to normal. You can also check keyboard layout here.  [Right-to-left language features](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Right-to-left-language-features-17d8a34d-36d6-49ad-b765-257cb7cd22e2#__toc254700152)
For left to right typing:-
Have you tried - Home file -> paragraph -> left to right radio button or button.
For columns:-
Change left to right and default language [if right to left] then test to see if tables have changed [as they should], if not create a new template with 3 new columns or highlight the right side column and drag to the left, then the new middle to the right.
Hope this helps in someway.